# How to use Variable in Select Layer By Attribute in Model Builder

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro

I have a Variable `Types` (Multiple Strings) in my model and would like to use the variable with the tool `Select Layer By Attribute` and a where clause `TYPE IN (%Types%)`.

However, `%Types%` is a semicolon (`;`) separated string, e.g. `'Type1;Type2'` but what I need is a list of strings (which I would have expected considering that it's a variable with multiple values).

Does ArcGIS Pro has any built-in function to use the variable `Types` for this use case, or do I have to write a Python script to accomplish this?

I haven't found anything in the SQL reference on the ArcGIS Pro's help page:
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm

Comment: Essentially, are you asking "How do I parse a string coming in as foo;bar;foo into a comma separated (or other) list"? As you've explained your problem, the string parameter will be passed exactly as it is, into the SQL Expression, as you've correctly pointed out.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I am aware of. I am looking for a possibility to transform the string or another builtin function so I can use this variable. (I know how to achieve it with Python but I hope(d) there is a way to achieve it with the Model Builder itself.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write a little bit of Python.

You can add **Calculate Value** from the **Utilities** menu in ModelBuilder.

You don't need to write a full function, you can supply the following as an expression:
`str(tuple(%Types%.split(";")))`

This assumes you have a parameter named **Types** as you've mentioned in your question.

Input:  `"foo;bar;foo2;bar2"`

Output: `('foo', 'bar', 'foo2', 'bar2')`

Alternatively, if you will NOT have the " " as part of the input string (ie. `foo;bar;foo2;bar2`)
You can use the following expression with the quotes wrapping Types: `str(tuple("%Types%".split(";")))`

Comment: Thank you, too bad that there is no split function or something similar. In that case I am not going to use model builder and write everything with Python. Maybe I should suggest it in ArcGIS Idea. The I could have used a sub-query like here http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html.

Comment: Not to dissuade you from logging an idea - I'll just say where would individual parsing tools start and stop? Its easier to have a single tool that you can modify (ie put some Python in. Granted, yes, you do need to figure out the specific Python for the scenario as the end user vs having an out of the box tool to do what you want with a couple UI input for ease of use.

Comment: I usually rather go with a script than with model builder... however, it would be nice if there would be a few more built-in functions available. Especially in this case since one would assume to get a list of string rather than a string separated with semicolons when creating a variable with multiple values.